# How can I remove the Static Front Page option from the Customizer

Tags: theme-development, customization

In Wordpress 4.1's Theme Customizer there's a **Static Front Page** option.
I've set up my theme to have a custom front page (via `front-page.php` in the theme) so I don't want this option to be available here.

[image]

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code will do the job.

```
add_action('customize_register', 'themename_customize_register');
function themename_customize_register($wp_customize) {
  $wp_customize->remove_section( 'static_front_page' );
}
```

It will remove Static Front Page option.

Details [here](https://cruxwireweb.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/remove-default-sections-in-wordpress-theme-customizer/)