# How to set wp_options in functions.php for removeing the Default Front Page

Tags: theme-development, frontpage, options

I want to disable the default front page as I want to show always the first listed page in the frontend. Therefor I [disable the Static Front Page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/176684/74281).

But I have also to set in **wp_options** the variables **show_on_front** and **page_on_front** to remove the old default Front Page.

I can manipulate the variables in the DB:

```sql
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'page' WHERE option_name = 'show_on_front';    
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '0' WHERE option_name = 'page_on_front';
```

How can I set this variables fix in my `functions.php`? Or is that the wrong approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following:

```
update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
update_option( 'page_on_front', '0' );
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, that's what I was looking for!